# Apps for car safety?

Tags: android, windows-phone, car

I have recently brought a car which I'm forced to keep it outside, away from my direct look for most of the time and am really concerned for it being getting stolen.

I am looking for an app which would help me in preventing car theft.

What I am looking for:

I have two mobile devices - one running Android and other running Windows. I want an app that I can install on one the device and leave it in the car with GPS enabled.

As soon as the car moves, it should send alert to the other device that I have with me. Is there such an app?

Comment: This is an interesting idea. What version of Android and Windows are the devices running?

Comment: Windows: 8.1   Android: 4.4.2